# Assimilation to men

Tags: sunni

Assalamu aleykum! Brothers and sisters, I’m confused, I really need your opinion. Perhaps, we all know that trying to resemble men if you’re a girl and visa versa is haram. I try to look and behave very feminine and kind, but I study civil engineering and robotics. I’m afraid now that as it is considered more of a masculine profession I fall under that category of a girl who resembles men. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

Waalaikumsalam.

There is nothing wrong with your study or any other studies as long as it does not go against the law of Islam. Another question that can be highlighted here is that can a woman actually works on the construction site? Will the woman resembles a man?

The points referring to "man resemble to a woman or vise versa" here is when a person for example a man, has a strong desire in their hearts to be a woman. The man who cross the law of Islam are the one who are cursed by Allah SWT. If your ni'at is just to study and increase your knowledge on your profesion, then it is absolutely fine.

Wallahualam.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply!!! Well, now I’m confused, would I resemble a man if I work on the construction side?( I’m going to inherit my father’s mining company, so I actually won’t work on the construction place directly and most of the time will work from home or office, but now I’m really worried, cause I still sometimes must go and watch how construction is going (my ancle would be there, so, hopefully, there won’t be problems with mixing). So, do you think, I would resemble men if I work on the construction side?(

Comment: No, you would not. Working in a construction side or mining profession does not make you a man if you are a woman. The job itself is a job that is in accordance with sharia. It is not illegal or tends towards doing something illegal or in this context, resembles a man. The explanation above covers it.

Comment: OK, thanks!!!!!